# Word for the satisfaction of curiosity

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a good feeling you get when your curiosity is satisfied, especially if is about a question you found interesting or important, or have spent a lot of time and energy trying to answer. Depending on how much I wanted to know, this feeling can be quite pleasing. Is there a word specifically for either the satisfaction of a curiosity, or the feeling that results?

Comment: @ermanen agreed, I think that any way you cut it, you'll have to specify curiosity so that people understand.

Comment: Perhaps *enlightened*

Comment: In my opinion, the question is not asking for alternatives to satisfy or satisfied but most answers are going towards that. There isn't a single word for this specific situation and the best fit is still "satisfied" in the context.

Answer (score 9):

I feel ***[sated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/sated)*** when a need has been fulfilled, including curiosity, for example: **"Learning of the contents of the box in the movie "7" has *sated*
my, and Brad Pitt's, curiosity."**

> from MWO:
>
> **Sate** - verb, **Sated** - adjective
>
> "having one's appetite completely satisfied"

Comment: Is "sated" preferable to "satiated"?

Comment: @blueintegral Hmm, to me "satiated" like it is more strongly with respect to food. "sated" could be interpreted like that too, but (to me at least) less so than "satiated"

Comment: Why would we choose "sated" instead of "satisfied"? The question was not asking for an alternative to "satisfy" or "satisfied".

Comment: @ermanen, "sated", to me, is a degree more satisfying that "satisfied".  I can eat a salad and have my hunger satisfied, but if I eat a steak and a potato with that salad, I'm more likely to feel "sated".   It's a nuance.

Comment: But it is still not a better fit than "satisfied". It is just a nice alternative and the question is not asking for an alternative or another degree. The common phrase is "satisfy one's curiosity".

Comment: @ermanen There's the nuance - having one's curiosity satisfied is the idiomatic expression most often used - but for something that has been driving you nuts, another expression that conveys a higher degree of satisfaction might be desired.  Don't you love English? :-).

Comment: @Kristina: I wouldn't bother commenting if I didn't love English. I always try my best when answering the questions as well. You also give good answers. But I just made my point about the question and the answer, it is not about me.

Answer (score 9):

This is what you get from [Google Books Search](http://googlebooks.byu.edu/x.asp), with the search term, `curiosity was [v*]`.

[image]

The best options seem to be:

- satisfied
- gratified
- appeased
- sated
- fed

All these words are quite generic, though. I did not see anything relevant that goes better with "curiosity" than with anything else.

Answer (score 2):

After I have been satisfied I feel very **content**.

> a state of satisfaction.

If I am obnoxiously satisfied with a little smirk, one might say I am **smug**.

> an excessive feeling of self-satisfaction

Answer (score 1):

I would like to call "satisfaction of curiosity" as **knowledge (or knowing)** if we really want to go with a single word. Because you know something when you satisfy your curiosity.

> [curiosity:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/curiosity) A desire to know or learn.

---

Though, there isn't a single word for satisfaction that is only associated with curiosity. In most cases, "satisfaction" or "satisfied" can be used depending on the context.

The common phrase is "**satisfy one's curiosity**" as you mentioned in the question.

Other than that, **relief** and **reward** is used in some technical sources.

> The drive to learn new information or perform some action is often initiated by the anticipation of **reward (an emotional sensation of relief and happiness).** In this way, the concepts of motivation and reward are intrinsically tied to the phenomenon of curiosity.

<sub>~Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiosity</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **enlightened**, **apprised**, or **informed**?

- [**enlightened**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enlightened) - "Made aware of something."
- [**apprise**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apprise) - "To notify, or to make aware; to inform."
- [**informed**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/informed) - "Instructed; having knowledge of a fact or area of education."

Of the three, I'd go with **enlightened** as it seems to have the most positive connotations (to me at least).

Answer (score 0):

Hyperhedonia: [The feeling of an abnormally great pleasure in any act or happening.
[hyper- + G. hēdonē, pleasure]](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/hyperhedonia)

Comment: I don't think this actually fits, because hyperhedonia implies something not within the bounds of normal responses. My curiosity can be sated when I find out the answer to a riddle, but if I'm exhibiting hyperhedonia I think people will correctly assume something is wrong with me.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that my curiosity is [satiated](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/satiate) (*rassasier* in French).

Answer (score 0):

"grokked" works to an extent.  And, since "curiosity killed the cat, but satisfaction brought it back", maybe "reincarnated".

Answer (score -1):

afterglow - (noun) it is a pleasant effect or feeling that lingers after something is done, experienced, or achieved.

also contentment, satiation or triumphant.

Comment: itself from the Merriam Webster dictionary